# Shell scrilpt : binary operator expected

Tags: while-loop, sh

I have a bug in my shell script, I know it is at the while loop but I cant see it, I already check spaces. I also try to use test instead  of  parenthesis but I have the same error

If I comment the while loop my code works

```
line 45: [: -1e: binary operator expected
```

my code is

```
#!/bin/sh

# pe request
#$ -pe mpi_16 32 
#### 16 core : 'mpi_16 16' || 24 core : 'mpi_24 24 '

# our Job name 
#$ -N test3MD

#$ -S /bin/sh

#$ -q dulce.q
#### 16 core : '2687wv2.q'  || 24 core : '2697v2.q'

#$ -V

#$ -cwd

# needs in 
#   $NSLOTS          
#      the number of tasks to be used
#   $TMPDIR/machines 
#       a valid machiche file to be passed to mpirun 
#   enables $TMPDIR/rsh to catch rsh calls if available

echo "Got $NSLOTS slots."
cat $TMPDIR/machines

################ mpi execute #############################
MPI_HOME=/opt/intel/impi/4.0.0.028
MPI_EXEC=$MPI_HOME/bin64/mpirun
 cd $SGE_O_WORKDIR

rm ./POTCAR
cat /share/VASP_POTCAR/PAW_PBE_VASP52/C/POTCAR >./POTCAR
cat /share/VASP_POTCAR/PAW_PBE_VASP52/Li/POTCAR >>./POTCAR

runVASP=/opt/vasp/vasp.5.4/vasp.5.4.1/bin/vasp_std
runVASP_NonCol=/opt/vasp/vasp.5.4/vasp.5.4.1/bin/vasp_ncl
runVASP_GAMMA=/opt/vasp/vasp.5.4/vasp.5.4.1/bin/vasp_gam


  i=1

  while [ $i -1e 10 ] 
  do
     cp POSCAR  POSCAR.$i
     $MPI_EXEC -machinefile $TMPDIR/machines -n $NSLOTS $runVASP > stdout
     cp CONTCAR POSCAR
     cp REPORT REPORT.$i
     cp HILLSPOT PENALTY
     let i=i+1
  done
```

Thanks

Comment: Just at a glance, it looks like you want `-le`, not `-1e`.

Comment: yes,  it is thanks!